# Proving a property with the Euclidean division properties

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I am trying to prove that any square AND cube number (that is, any number which is the square and the cube of other two numbers, for example $64=8^2=4^3$, I don't know if this has a proper nomenclature since I'm not native) can be written as either $7k $  or  $ 7k+1$

The problem here is that I can only use the Euclidean division property to prove it:

```
Given two integers a and b, with b ≠ 0, there exist unique integers q and r such that

a = bq + r

and

0 ≤ r < |b|
```

I also guess I can use the following properties related to the problem, which I managed to prove beforehand:

```
The square of any number can be written as 3k or 3k+1

The cube of any number can be written as 9k or 9k+1 or 9k+8
```

Using this, I have tried to analyse the remainders $r=0$ and $r=1$ for $a=7q+r$, then study $a^2$ and $a^3$ with said expression on each case and check if they are divisible for any of their respective possible expressions as square or cube, but I was not able to prove any of them apart from $a^2$ in $r=0$

I am not sure if I should prove it this way, if I am missing something or if there is any other way to do this, help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

A number which is simultaneously square *and* cube is necessarily a number which is a perfect power of six.

> Continuing with your thought process of looking at modulo $7$, what are the possible values of $a^6\pmod{7}$?

$~$

> Note that $6=7-1$, that $7$ is prime, and remember [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

Comment: Thanks! got it.

Comment: @Lightsong **Simpler** $\bmod 7\!:\ a\not\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, a\equiv \dfrac{a^3}{a^2}\equiv \dfrac{(b^2)^3}{(c^3)^2}\equiv \dfrac{b^6}{c^6}\equiv \dfrac{1}1\,$ by little Fermat $\ \ $